# Unexpected exception while parsing with XercesDOMParser

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, xerces-c

I am using xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-windows-vc-10.0 to develop code in C++, using MS Developer Studio 10.0.4 on Windows 7 Professional SP1. I use the following code, from [here](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-sax-3.html), to open and close XML files.

```
try
{
    XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
}
catch (const XMLException& toCatch) 
{
    char* message = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.getMessage());
    cout << "Error during initialization! :\n"
            << message << "\n";
    XMLString::release(&message);
    return ERROR_PARAMETERS;
}

// Determine xml file name
xmlsFileName.assign(fileName);      

XercesDOMParser* parser = new XercesDOMParser();
parser->setValidationScheme(XercesDOMParser::Val_Always);
parser->setDoNamespaces(true); 

ErrorHandler* errHandler = (ErrorHandler*) new HandlerBase();
parser->setErrorHandler(errHandler);

try 
{
    parser->parse(xmlsFileName.c_str());
}
catch (const XMLException& toCatch) 
{
    char* message = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.getMessage());
    cout << "Exception message is: \n"
            << message << "\n";
    XMLString::release(&message);
    return ERROR_PARAMETERS;
}
catch (const DOMException& toCatch) 
{
    char* message = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.msg);
    cout << "Exception message is: \n"
            << message << "\n";
    XMLString::release(&message);
    return ERROR_PARAMETERS;
}
catch (...) 
{
    cout << "Unexpected Exception \n" ;
    return ERROR_PARAMETERS;
}

// Some more code

delete parser;
delete errHandler;
```

The input XML files have the naming sequence `rootname-00000.xml`, `rootname-00001.xml`, etc.  Everything works fine until I get to `rootname-03799.xml` at which point

```
parser->parse(xmlsFileName.c_str());
```

fails with parser->parse(xmlsFileName.c_str());

If I change its name to `rootname-00000.xml` I have no problems so it appears that there is no problem with the format of the file.  Also, I delete the parser and error handler every time so it seems that I should not be running out of anything.

Any assistance with this problem would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you check the memory consumption during this task? Does it increase? I don't know what you are doing with the parsed document but if you just want to load all of them to check if they are well-formed you can also use the SAX parser in Xerces which is much faster and doesn't keep the whole file as tree in memory.

Comment: And you can also use the SAX parser if you want to validate the XML ...